# How can I filter a DataColumn on a TimeSpan value?

Tags: datatable, timespan, rowfilter

Programming in C#.NET. I have a `DataTable` with a column named Time which is of type `System.TimeSpan`. When I display the `DataTable` in a `DataGridView` I want to filter out all the entries that don't have a time listed. I have tried the following but to no avail. Can you help?

```cs
DataView myDataView = new DataView(SomeDataTable);
myDataView.RowFilter += "Time >= 1";  // doesn't work
myDataView.RowFilter += "Time >= #00:00:01#";  // doesn't work
myDataView.RowFilter += "Time <> ''";  // doesn't work
myDataView.RowFilter += "Time <> ''";  // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it...

```
myDataView.RowFilter = "Convert(Time, System.String) <> ''";
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone bump into this annoying problem, unfortunately there is no good solve.
It seams that filter `DataTable` with `System.TimeSpan` is not working.
The solution I use is to change the type of the column in the SQL to `NVARCHAR(8)` from `Time(0)` (or whatever) and then you can just apply logic upon it like so:

```cs
StringBuilder builder = new();

// IsNull() is my own string extension
if (!ExecutionTimeFrom.IsNull())
{
    builder.Append($"AND TimeStamp >= '{ExecutionTimeFrom}' ");
}
if (!ExecutionTimeTo.IsNull())
{
    builder.Append($"AND TimeStamp <= '{ExecutionTimeTo}' ");
}
```

Afterward convert string from the sql table from `hh:mm:ss` (10:32:15) back into `System.TimeSpan` is as easy as:

```cs
bool isTimeSpan = TimeSpan.TryParse(TimeFromSql, out TimeSpan time);
```

I break my head on this for two days, I hope it will help :)